# How to work with Arrays inside of classes c++

Tags: c++

I just started to learn C++. Maybe the Question is stupid, but please be nice. I want to write a Class for a linear Congruence Generator. In this Class I wanna write the calculated Values into an Array, but it dosen't work.
I would be very thankful, if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class KongruenzGenerator
{
    

private:
    int a;
    int c;
    int m;
    int x0;
    int Array[20];

public:
    KongruenzGenerator(int a, int c, int m, int x0);
    int Calculation();
};

KongruenzGenerator::KongruenzGenerator(int a, int c, int m, int x0)
{
     this -> a = a, this -> c = c, this -> m = m, this -> x0 = x0;
}

int KongruenzGenerator::Calculation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Array) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Array[i] = x0;
            cout << Array[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            Array[i]= (a * Array[i - 1] + c) % m;
            cout << Array[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    KongruenzGenerator instanz(60,0,200,4);
    instanz.Calculation();
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "doesn't work" ? Do you get compiler errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: "it dosen't work" doesn't describe what it should do, what it does do, or why you think your code implements what it should do

Comment: [What do you mean "it doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, what do you think the problem is?

Comment: You may want to select better parameters. You have a few examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: Also, using `int` isn't a good idea. Use an unsigned type with fixed word length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact your `Array` works correctly. However, just think about the content of your Array:

```
Array[0] = x0 = 4
Array[1] = (60 * Array[0] + 0) % 200 = 240 % 200 = 40
Array[2] = (40 * Array[1] + 0) % 200 = 1600 % 200 = 0
Array[3] = (0 + 0) % 200 = 0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is spot on and this is just a follow up with two examples of using some parameters listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator. These parameters are *not* chosen at random but must be carefully selected to create a good PRNG and these are typically not set during runtime but using template parameters and then providing `typedef`s for different LCG:s. You typically only want the user to have to provide the *seed* to the chosen LCG.

I'll give an example of using one 32 bit and one 64 bit generator. Note that the internal state of a LCG does not need to be a complete array of values. You only need to keep the previous value.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, T a, T c, T m>
class KongruenzGenerator {
private:
    T x0;

public:
    KongruenzGenerator(T seed) : x0(seed) {}

    T operator()() {
        if constexpr (m == 0) x0 = a * x0 + c;
        else x0 = (a * x0 + c) % m;

        return x0;        
    }
};

using NumericalRecipes = KongruenzGenerator<uint32_t, 1664525, 1013904223, 0>;
using MMIX = KongruenzGenerator<uint64_t, 6364136223846793005, 1442695040888963407, 0>;

int main()
{   
    NumericalRecipes i1(4);
    MMIX i2(4);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << i1() << ' ' << i2() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1020562323 8452495862566583811
2754714582 13512857827340264662
2398167357 14341745989969716461
3504402808 6046934036216779256
214500983 570255399585984999
2631315818 5893111806738489322
291516865 18048486130794099569
1308450860 3573853742175050540
2330615195 16796199018521517067
3485759038 8375325528806204478
```

In order to be able to use the generator with one of the [*RandomNumberDistributions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution), like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) it must fulfill the named requirement [*UniformRandomBitGenerator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator). This means that you need to add `min()`, `max()` and `result_type`. Example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

template<typename T, T a, T c, T m>
class KongruenzGenerator {
private:
    T x0;

public:
    using result_type = T;
    static constexpr T min() { return 0; }
    static constexpr T max() {
        if constexpr (m == 0) return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
        return m - 1;
    }

    constexpr KongruenzGenerator(T seed) : x0(seed) {}   

    constexpr T operator()() {
        if constexpr (m == 0) x0 = a * x0 + c;
        else x0 = (a * x0 + c) % m;
        return x0;        
    }
};

using NumericalRecipes = KongruenzGenerator<uint32_t, 1664525, 1013904223, 0>;
using MMIX = KongruenzGenerator<uint64_t, 6364136223846793005, 1442695040888963407, 0>;

int main() {   
    NumericalRecipes i1(4);
    MMIX i2(4);

    // Generate values in the range [-10, 10] using a distribution:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d1(-10, 10);


    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) std::cout << d1(i1) << '\t' << d1(i2) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
-6  -1
3   5
1   6
7   -4
-9  -10
2   -4
-9  10
-4  -6
1   9
7   -1
```